Avoid Kotlin Annotation Class from Obfuscating in Proguard Rules
I have a Kotlin annotation class as below -
import androidx.annotation.StringDef

const val GRANT_TYPE_REFRESH_TOKEN = "refresh_token"
const val GRANT_TYPE_ACCESS_TOKEN = "access_token"

@StringDef(GRANT_TYPE_ACCESS_TOKEN, GRANT_TYPE_REFRESH_TOKEN)
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.SOURCE)
annotation class TokenGrantType

This class is part of an SDK that i release on Maven.
Once i publish the SDK to Maven and using the gradle dependency of this SDK. Everything is getting resolved but only the values in this annotation class are not getting retained.
@kotlin.annotation.Target @kotlin.annotation.Retention public final annotation class PaymentFlow public constructor() : kotlin.Annotation {

}
Kindly suggest how i can keep the String Constants in above class.
